# How to use Agora Electron SDK in linux and window 64bit?

Tags: electron, agora.io

I want to implement video and voice call feature in our project, but **Linux** and **Window64 bit** doesn't support **Agora Electron SDK.** So, is there any way to use **Agora Electron SDK** in **linux** and **Window64 bit**?

Comment: Currently linux is not supported for the Electron SDK. For Windows64 bit, I would suggest you to file a ticket here: https://agora-ticket.agora.io/